# Using a js widget in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, widget

I'm trying to use a js widget (https://youglish.com/widget.jsp) in my angular4 personal project, but I don't have experience in angular4 and javascript neither. I would like some help to change the parameter.

I put the js reference in index.html

:

```
    <script async src="https://youglish.com/public/emb/widget.js"charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

And in  the component, I put like in the example:

youglish.component.html

```
<p>
Youglish Test
</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" (click)="changeText()">Load </button>


<a id="yg-widget-0" class="youglish-widget" data-query="polyglot" data-components="248" data-toggle-ui="1"  href="https://youglish.com">Visit YouGlish.com</a>
```

But I'm not able to bind the parameter like this: data-query="{{searchWord}}".

```
<a id="yg-widget-0" class="youglish-widget" data-query="{{searchWord}}" data-components="248" data-toggle-ui="1"  href="https://youglish.com">Visit YouGlish.com</a>
```

This gives me an error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'query' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("

<a id="yg-widget-0" class="youglish-widget" [ERROR ->]data-query="{{searchWord}}" data-components="248" data-toggle-ui="1"  href="https://youglish.com">Visit"): ng:///AppModule/YouglishComponent.html@7:44
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
```

youglish.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'youglish',
  templateUrl: './youglish.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./youglish.component.css']
})
export class YouglishComponent implements OnInit {

  searchWord: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  changeText(){

    this.searchWord = 'Welcome';
  }

}
```

Somebody know how I can bind the word in widget?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are going to have to learn more about Angular. What you are missing is the fundamentals of angular. Please go through the tutorial at  https://angular.io/tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use an input binding directive:

```
<a id="yg-widget-0" class="youglish-widget" [data-query]="searchWord" data-components="248" data-toggle-ui="1"  href="https://youglish.com">Visit YouGlish.com</a>
```

Or apply the item as a string:

```
<a id="yg-widget-0" class="youglish-widget" data-query="'{{searchWord}}'" data-components="248" data-toggle-ui="1"  href="https://youglish.com">Visit YouGlish.com</a>
```